# From where I can find Qt scratch pad

Tags: qt

I'm reading Qt Designer manual. And found following para saying;

> "Qt Designer provides a scratch pad feature that allows you to collect
>   frequently used objects in a separate category. The scratch pad
>   category can be filled with any widget currently displayed in a form
>   by dragging them from the form and dropping them onto the widget box.
>   These widgets can be used in the same way as any other widgets, but
>   they can also contain child widgets. Open a context menu over a widget
>   to change its name or remove it from the scratch pad."

I was searched for scratch pad, but nothing found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dragging a widget (it can have nested child widgets in) from the form editor onto the list of stock widgets on the left, it should add the dragged widget into a new subgroup "Scratchpad". The scratch pad will only appear then.

> The scratch pad category can be filled with any widget currently
>   displayed in a form by dragging them from the form and dropping them
>   onto the widget box.

It is a little ambiguous, but by "widget box" they mean this guy:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's better user can get the Scratchpad Category to top of the Widget Box.

Comment: @HareenLaks - it doesn't seem to be possible, you can however collapse the widget groups which will bring the scratchpad up.

Comment: Realizing this is an ancient post, but Mrs Google is of no help. Is is possible to "drag and drop" the ENTIRE form layout?